# hiveserver2 error showing while starting it

Tags: hive

I am not able to start hiveserver2,when iI start, it shows no response. As shown

```
hive --service hiveserver2
which: no hbase in (/opt/hadoop/hive/apache-hive-2.3.4-bin/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/java/default/bin:/opt/hadoop/sbin:/opt/hadoop/bin)
```

2019-01-09 07:20:24: Starting HiveServer2

I have also tried it with another command

```
hive --service hiveserver2 --hiveconf hive.server2.thrift.port=10000 --hiveconf hive.root.logger=INFO,console
ERROR [main] metastore.ObjectStore: Version information found in metastore differs 2.0.0 from expected schema version 2.3.0. Schema verififcation is disabled hive.metastore.schema.verification
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you recently perform an upgrade? 
Hive is expecting schema version 2.3.0 per your error. You should use the Hive Schema tool to upgrade the schema version.

- stop hive services
- backup your hive backend db
- upgrade metastore with schematool. Ex for postgres (possible backends are  derby|mysql|postgres|oracle|mssql);

  /bin/schematool -dbType *postgres* -info

  /bin/schematool -dbType *postgres* -upgradeSchemaFrom -upgradeSchemaFrom 2.0.0 -dryRun

  /bin/schematool -dbType *postgres* -upgradeSchemaFrom -upgradeSchemaFrom 2.0.0
- start hive server

Further examples and information about this process is documented at: 
https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/Hive+Schema+Tool

Comment: When i run ,./cygnus-flume-ng agent --conf /opt/nec/scfw/volumes/cygnus/fiware-cygnus/cygnus-ngsi/conf/ --conf-file /opt/nec/scfw/volumes/cygnus/fiware-cygnus/cygnus-ngsi/conf/agent_hdfs.conf --name cygnus-ngsi -Dflume.root.logger=INFO,console
Shows error: Failed to open new session: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException(org.apache.hadoop.security.authorize.AuthorizationException): Unauthorized connection for super-user: hadoop from IP x.x.x.x.